# TabView and Timer is not working for automated carousel in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I am trying to have a carousel in SwiftUI which automatically sliding to the next page. I implemented the solution below:

```
struct CarouselView: View {
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @State var selection = 0
    
    let carouselViews: Array<WelcomeImageModel> =[....]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(carouselViews) { view in
                    ZStack {
                        Image(view.image)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                        VStack {
                            Text(view.title)
                 
                            Text(view.description)
                               
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
            .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
                withAnimation{
                    selection = selection < 5 ? selection + 1 : 0
                }
            })
            
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

The `WelcomeImageModel` is just a struct to better handle the data, and it's not relevent here but there is 5 elements in it.

It seems that the `selection` is not updating properly. If I manually slide, it came back to 0 automatically. any idea why selection is not properly increasing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tag` of your tabs probably doesn't match your `selection`! Your tabs are automatically tagged with the `id`s of your `WelcomeImageModel`s, by the `ForEach`, and not 0 to 5 as your `selection` expects.

An easy solution is to change the `ForEach` to:

```
ForEach(carouselViews.indices, id: \.self) { i in
    // use carouselViews[i] in here...
}
```

This will tag each tab with the index of tab.

Alternatively, add a `index` property in `WelcomeImageModel`.

```
struct WelcomeImageModel: Identifiable {
    let image: String
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let index: Int // add this

    // I'm not sure how you implemented id
}
```

Give the models the indices 0 to 4, in the order that they appear.

```
let carouselViews: [WelcomeImageModel] = [
    .init(...., index: 0),
    .init(...., index: 1),
    .init(...., index: 2),
    .init(...., index: 3),
    .init(...., index: 4),
]
```

Then you can do:

```
ForEach(carouselViews) { view in
    ZStack {
        // ...    
    }.tag(view.index)
}
```